# Replace word in files with random words from txt using sed

Tags: shell, awk, sed, replace, find

I have over 500 site and i want to replace a specific word in all of them with random words from a text file.

Folders structure

```
www
- site1
- - idex.html
- site2
- - index.html
-site3
- - index.html
```

Word name: Dashemd

Txt file content one world per line, like this:

```
Hemd.txt:
Blue
Red
Pink
Green
More …
```

So i need replace word `dashemd` in index.html of all folders with list of words in `hemd.txt` file randomly.

Could you please help me?

I tried to replace with static word but i couldn’t do this with random words from txt file

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/dashemd/newworld/g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace **each** repetitive **'dashemd'** words:

```
find ./ -type f -name '*.html' -exec perl -i -MFile::Slurp -pe '
    my @words = split /\n/, read_file("Hemd.txt");
    s/dashemd/$words[rand(@words)]/g;
' -- {} +
```

You need [File::Slurp](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp) module, `libfile-slurp-perl` Debian package. A must have.
Can also be installed via `cpan -i File::Slurp`

Comment: It works great but there is a little issue, i have more than one dashemd in every index.html and script using one word from txt file for each file. So i see one world replaced many times in a file and next world in next files…

Comment: Actually i need replace dashemd with random words in each file too

Comment: Added new way to replace **all** needed words.

Answer (score 1):

I would harness `awk` or `perl` for this task; with `perl` being the easiest one:

```bash
find www -iname '*.html' -exec perl -i.orig -slpe '
    BEGIN {
        open FD, "<", $toFile;
        chomp(@toArr = <FD>);
        close(FD);
        exit 1 if $fromStr eq "" or @toArr == 0;
    }
    s/$fromStr/$toArr[rand(@toArr)]/g
' -- -fromStr=dashemd -toFile=Hemd.txt -- {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed, parallel and utils):

```
find . -name index.html |
parallel -q sed -Ei ':a;/dashemd/{x;s/.*/shuf hemd.txt | head -1/e;x
                     G;s/dashemd([^\n]*)\n(.*)/\2\1/;ta}' {}
```

Pipe the results of each `index.html` into a sed invocation.

For each occurrence of `dashemd` in the file generate a random word from the `hemd.txt` file, append it to the end of the line and then substitute it for the match.